# Multiple contact selection in Android

Tags: android, selection, contacts

Is it possible to get a multiple contact selection activity in Android?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be: Create a `ListView` containing the contacts including a `CheckBox` next to each of them

Or you also may want to check out [this](http://www.anddev.org/checkbox_text_list___extension_of_iconified_text_tutorial-t771.html) link

Comment: You are missing the point: sure I can do it myself, but I asked for a system intent or activity. There is one for single contact selection, and I wonder if there is a way to get multiple contact selection.

Comment: fair  enough - but I think you missed that point in your question ;-)

Comment: Sorry for that you are probably right :)
It is very simple to get the contacts and fill my own list, but I wanted to avoid that and use a "standard" intent/activity.